# dbo.fn_split function cutting off next character after the split character/delimeter

Tags: sql-server

I ran this query :

```
select * From dbo.fn_split('Age,15,14,193,188 ',',')
```

It's returning the values but cutting off one character in front of each value

I tried adding space after every comma like

```
select * From dbo.fn_split('Age, 15, 14, 193, 188 ',',')
```

And it worked. But I want to know why is not working with commas

```
select * From dbo.fn_split ('Age,15,14,193,188 ',',')
```

Comment: The obvious assumption should be that your split function is not working correctly. Don't reinvent the wheel - go find a splitting function that has already been written and tested.

Comment: I don't believe there is a  Microsoft SQL server standard function called "fn_split" more than likely this is a user defined function. If you can post the code of the function that would help anyone diagnose the issue. Alternatively if you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher use the built in function ''string_split" like 'select * from string_split('1,2,3,4,5,6',',')'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Regarding your question please add the code of the function `fn_split` since it's not a native function in SQL Server.

Comment: Who wouldn't be surprised if the OP's function (`fn_split`) uses a `CURSOR` or `WHILE` loop? :)

Comment: @Larnu there's some hope that it uses XML.

Comment: I've actually voted to close this as off topic. The OP has answered this question, however, not with an answer that will help anyone. The DDL of `fn_split` is required make the answer helpful (a good splitter would just return the final value as `'188 '`, not remove the first character of every value). This says that the function itself is flawed; which is impossible to trouble shoot without the DDL.

Comment: I'd agree, @LuisCazares, but the OP's picture (in his answer) gives ordinal position; which is impossible with an XML splitter. Maybe it's a JSON splitter, but I doubt it. Shame, as they will (more than likely) learn quickly that a iterative splitter is going to get slow, fast.

Answer (score 2):

You're not posting the code of fn_split which is where the problem resides. But if your strings are less than 8000 chars long, this function will help you to split them in an optimal way. This function is a modified version of [Jeff Moden's splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) made by Eirikur Eirikson.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
 WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20) = ',')

RETURNS @Strings TABLE

(

position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,

value varchar(8000)

)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @index int

SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)

BEGIN

```
SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 

IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 

  BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)

      BREAK 

  END 

IF (@index > 1) 

  BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  

    SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 

  END 

ELSE

  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))

END
```

RETURN

END

Comment: Found a quick fix inside the function basically LTRIM(RTRIM(@text)) before starts processing the @text

Answer (score -3):

I figured out what was I doing wrong. Basically I was adding an extra space at the end of string that I want to split. If you change

`Select * From dbo.fn_split(dbo.fn_split('Age,15,14,193,188 ',','))` to `Select * From dbo.fn_split('Age,15,14,193,188',',')`. In other words, get rid of the extra space after number 188 you will get the desired result.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX6GJ.png)

Comment: Without the DDL of `fn_split` this doesn't actually help anyone else. And the "Solution" is the result set, not the corrected SQL.